# Replace rows by index

Tags: r, data.table

In the following example:

```
library(data.table)
df1 <- data.table("1A"=c(0,0,0,0),"1B"=c(4:3),"2A"=c(0,0,0,0), "2B"=c(4:3))
df2 <- data.table("1A"=c(0,0),"1B"=c(1:2),"2A"=c(0,0), "2B"=c(1:2))

df1
#    1A 1B 2A 2B
# 1:  0  4  0  4
# 2:  0  3  0  3
# 3:  0  4  0  4
# 4:  0  3  0  3

df2
#    1A 1B 2A 2B
# 1:  0  1  0  1
# 2:  0  2  0  2

indx = c(1,3)
indx
# [1] 1 3

df1[indx,] <- df2
df1
#    1A 1B 2A 2B
# 1:  0  1  0  1
# 2:  0  3  0  3
# 3:  0  2  0  2
# 4:  0  3  0  3
```

I successfully replace rows 1 and 3 in df1 with df2. Replicating the same exercise in my real data, I encounter the error:

> Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates
>   detected).

in this expression:

```
Z4[positionpdis,] <- ZpdisRow2
```

The objects have the following attributes:

```
is.data.table(ZpdisRow2)
# [1] TRUE
is.data.table(Z4)
# [1] TRUE
dim(Z4)
# [1] 7968 7968
dim(Z4[positionpdis,])
# [1]   48 7968
dim(ZpdisRow2)
# [1]   48 7968
str(positionpdis)
# int [1:48] 91 257 423 589 755 921 1087 1253 1419 1585 ...
> length(unique(positionpdis))
# [1] 48
```

What can be the source of the error?

Comment: are there duplicates in `positionpdis`? Check with `length(unique(positionpdis))`

Comment: There seems to be no duplicates, the length is 48.

Comment: Can you show a small example where it doesn't work?  It might be easier to debug in that way

Comment: mts and akrun: After restarting R for a second time, the error is gone without touching anything...I don't know what happened. Sorry for the inconvenience guys and thank you.

Comment: @David Sorry, didn't saw your comment.  I posted a solution based on one possible scenario.

Comment: @akrun It is OK, It is very informative anyway.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing that we might have some column names duplicated in the original dataset.  For example, if we change the 3rd column name as the same as the first one, we get an error.

```
colnames(df1)[3] <- '1A'
df1[indx,] <- df2
```

> Error in `[<-.data.table`(`*tmp*`, indx, , value = list(`1A` = c(0,
>   0),  : 
>        Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected).

We can make that column names unique with `make.unique` which is a convenient function for this type of cases without having to look each and every column name for duplicates.

```
 colnames(df1) <- make.unique(colnames(df1)) 
 df1[indx,] <- df2
 df1
 #  1A 1B 1A.1 2B
 #1:  0  1    0  1
 #2:  0  3    0  3
 #3:  0  2    0  2
 #4:  0  3    0  3
```

---

Another option that should also work with duplicate column names is `set`.  It is very efficient as the overhead in `[.data.table` is avoided.  Here, we loop through the column index (`seq_along(df1)`), and based on the row (`i`) and column (`j`) index, we `set` the values in 'df1' with the values of 'df2'.

```
 for(j in seq_along(df1)){
           set(df1, i= as.integer(indx), j=j, df2[[j]])
  }
 df1
#   1A 1B 1A 2B
#1:  0  1  0  1
#2:  0  3  0  3
#3:  0  2  0  2
#4:  0  3  0  3
```

Comment: Thank you akrun. As I said the error disappeared after restart but as you say the error seem to be related to the column names. Very informative!