# data.table error: Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected)

Tags: r, data.table, zoo

I'm getting this error:

> Can't assign to the same column twice in the same query (duplicates detected).

for the following code:

```
  timeseries = user_data[datatype==i, .(displaydate, measurementvalue)]
  temp.zoo<-zoo(timeseries$measurementvalue, timeseries$displaydate)
  m.av<-rollmean(temp.zoo, 10, fill = list(NA, NULL, NA))
  cat("here is as.numeric(m.av)", as.numeric(m.av))
  cat("here is relevant user data ")
  print(user_data[datatype==i])
  user_data[datatype==i]$m.av = as.numeric(m.av)
```

From my `print` statements I know that `as.numeric(m.av)` looks like:

```
NA NA NA NA 14.38319 13.03924 13.17212 11.79657 11.81756 12.57878 12.62703 13.20897 10.09858 11.22617 10.31993 13.61604 13.19733 12.44212 12.15407 11.07399 12.74679 12.77372 13.7383 15.97627 15.76673 13.54072 23.97822 24.40755 24.5321 25.20337 28.09863 31.52313 32.97009 29.39092 29.80759 NA NA NA NA NA
```

and `user_data[datatype==i]` looks like:

```
 measurementvalue         displaydate     userid      datatype    m.av
 18.356180        2016-04-21 20:41:15    zzqSTKkf8c        3       0
 6.307539         2016-04-22 03:08:42    zzqSTKkf8c        3       0
 24.597610        2016-04-22 03:17:13    zzqSTKkf8c        3       0
 16.240690        2016-04-22 03:46:04    zzqSTKkf8c        3       0
 8.190225         2016-04-22 22:52:26    zzqSTKkf8c        3       0
...
```

Here's what I tried:

- I logged the `length/nrow` properties and found that `as.numeric(m.av)` has a length of 40 and the relevant slice of the data table also has a row count of 40, so these should match up.
- I logged the `nrow` of the data table and also `unique(data.table)` and the number of rows is the same, so there do not appear to be duplicate rows.

What could this error mean? I've checked the following SO post, but it doesn't seem related to my problem:

[Replace rows by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31984836/replace-rows-by-index)

Any suggestions/corrections appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The syntax you're using `DT[i]$j <- v` is very unusual for this package. Maybe check out the data.table vignettes to see its usual syntax https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Please make the code in your question reproducible by including all inputs and library statements so anyone else can simply copy it from the question and paste it into their session.  See [mcve]

Comment: @Frank is being too polite. That syntax is simply bad. Use `DT[i, col := value]` instead.